# Laravel and JSON response

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "ownersList": [
       { "propertiesList": [],
         "email": "email@email.com"  },
       { "propertiesList": [],
         "email": "email2@email.com" }
    ]
}
```

How do I grab all of the `propertiesList` associated with a specific "email" value?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need anything fancy from Laravel to do this. You will probably want to use Guzzle (which is a Laravel dependency) since it's nice and easy CURL wrapper for PHP.

```
// assumes the API response is in variable $api_response_body_as_a_string
$o_api_response = json_decode($api_response_body_as_a_string);
$owners_list = $o_api_response->owners_list;
$propertiesList = NULL;
foreach($owners_list as $this_owner) {
    if('email@to.find' === $this_owner->email) {
        $propertiesList = $this_owner->$propertiesList;
        break;
    }
}
// $propertiesList has the result or is NULL
```

Original question (before OP clarification):

You currently don't have any code related to Laravel in your question, so I'll venture a guess that you are querying a table where propertiesList is a foreign key of the ownersList Model:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Otherwise, more information about your setup (models and relationships) will be necessary to help you.

Comment: No, it is a JSON response I get from an API call

Comment: I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" on the line "$owners_list = $o_api_response->owners_list;"

Comment: Got it to work with your concept with few modifications :)) thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$item = null;
array_walk($obj->ownersList, function($i) use (&$item) {
    if($i->email == 'email@email.com') $item = $i;
});

// Print out the item
dd($item);
```

I've used hard coded `'email@email.com'`, you may use a variable or whatever thing you have.

Answer (score 0):

I realise the question is quite old and has been answered, but a nice clean way with Laravel is to do something like:

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);

$properties = collect($json['ownersList'])
    ->where('email', 'email@email.com')
    ->pluck('propertiesList')->all();
```

Internally, this does similar things to the other questions, but it is much more fluent and easier to read and understand.

See the [Collection documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections) for more information.